# VBA Excel_Query Import Data Web_Issue with cell format in the result

Tags: excel, vba, url, formatting

I'm running a web query for an Excel sheet and have been able to collect data from the website Yahoo-finance. However, instead of having numbers in every cells concerning the stock price of a ticker, my Excel sheet is filled with text and numbers. For instance,the result is the following :

> ```
> Date              close
> August 7, 2019    2.015 (correct)
> August 6, 2019    févr.50 or 01.02.3750 (wrong -> right data is 2.375 )
> August 5, 2019    janv.00 or 01.01.98 (wrong -> right data is 1.98)
> ```

Please find below my code. Could you please advise me how I must change my code? Many thanks in advance for your help.

```
 Dim url As String
    url = "URL;https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BALYO.PA/history?period1=1496959200&period2=1565128800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=url, Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))

        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Comment: How are your "wrong data" cells formatted?  Try formatting as number.

Answer (score 0):

Your same code, without text formatting:

```
Sub test()
 Dim url As String
    url = "URL;https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BALYO.PA/history?period1=1496959200&period2=1565128800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=url, Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))

        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

It is reporting:

[image: This]

With a header I already hide.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I copied / pasted your code. Unfortunately, it does not work. I do no get the same result than you. I still have a mix of numbers and text in the cells.

Comment: Furthermore, do you know  how can I change my code in order to get in the result only the 3 Following columns : Date / Adj Close / Volume ?

Comment: I will reply to your second comment aa soon I reach to my office. Regarding the first comment, iff hat code is running for me, should works for you so what are you getting? What is not working?

Comment: There are 2 options: 1) The page have headers and some plugins that are not possible to remove from the query, so just, on the macro, as soon as you get the result of it, delete the data you are not using.    2) In that page there is an option to receive a CSV file that it can be imported through the Excel Assistant to get just the data you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried again and it works now. I changed my code to remove columns after getting the result.

Comment: As a good practice, if my code helps you with your problem just check as answer. If not, post your own code as answer so next time, somebody like you can find an answer